# How to show the image in push notification (Gcm) android?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

From two days I am trying to get like this. But I failed. Please any one suggest me how to get image in push notification. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Code what I tried:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void handleMessage(Context mContext, Intent intent) {
    Bitmap remote_picture = null;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int icon = R.drawable.reload_logo;
    try {
        Bundle gcmData = intent.getExtras();
        if(intent.getExtras().getString("message")!=null)
            Log.v("TAG_IMAGE", "" + intent.getExtras().getString("message"));
        Log.v("TAG_IMAGE", "" + intent.getExtras().getString("imageurl"));


        {
            NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
            notiStyle.setSummaryText(intent.getExtras().getString("message"));

            try {
                remote_picture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(intent.getExtras().getString("imageurl")).getContent());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            notiStyle.bigPicture(remote_picture);
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = null;

            Intent gotoIntent = new Intent();
            gotoIntent.setClassName(mContext, "com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.MainActivity");//Start activity when user taps on notification.
            contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,
                    (int) (Math.random() * 100), gotoIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    mContext);
            Notification notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker("Reload.in").setWhen(0)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle("Reload.in")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(intent.getExtras().getString("message")))
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setLargeIcon(remote_picture)
                    .setContentText(intent.getExtras().getString("message"))
                    .setStyle(notiStyle).build();


            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            count++;
            notificationManager.notify(count, notification);//This will generate seperate notification each time server sends.
        }
    }catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting small icon and large icon are with same image. But I gave different.

result:

Comment: please any one help me.

Comment: Please explain the things that you have already tried?

Comment: Did you tried passing a `json String` containing the image url as the **message** and parse from it?

Comment: So your question was not 'how to show such notification' all you want is how you will get such image?, ofCourse, as @Boss said, you can pass a `JSON` which contains the url. Once you received the push, you can parse it and get the url, and download the image and show it wherever you want.

Comment: @kartheekij  how u handled notification image size ?

Comment: @Darpan hi, according to your comment, will be push processed (image parsed and shown) before we see push on the screen, will be we able to see image before we have clicked on push?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

thank you @Ravi.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void handleMessage(Context mContext, Intent intent) {
        Bitmap remote_picture = null;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int icon = R.drawable.reload_logo;
        Bundle gcmData = intent.getExtras();
        //if message and image url
        if(intent.getExtras().getString("message")!=null && intent.getExtras().getString("imageurl")!=null) {
            try {


                Log.v("TAG_IMAGE", "" + intent.getExtras().getString("message"));
                Log.v("TAG_IMAGE", "" + intent.getExtras().getString("imageurl"));


                NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
                notiStyle.setSummaryText(intent.getExtras().getString("message"));

                try {
                    remote_picture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(intent.getExtras().getString("imageurl")).getContent());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                notiStyle.bigPicture(remote_picture);
                notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = null;

                Intent gotoIntent = new Intent();
                gotoIntent.setClassName(mContext, "com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.MainActivity");//Start activity when user taps on notification.
                contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,
                        (int) (Math.random() * 100), gotoIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        mContext);
                Notification notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker("Reload.in").setWhen(0)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle("Reload.in")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(intent.getExtras().getString("message")))
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))

                        .setContentText(intent.getExtras().getString("message"))
                        .setStyle(notiStyle).build();


                notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                count++;
                notificationManager.notify(count, notification);//This will generate seperate notification each time server sends.

            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

for multi line:

```
 .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(intent.getExtras().getString("message"))) // use this
```

Comment: What should be the dimensions of this image so that it can give similar look on all android devices with cropping?

Comment: size of image in notification is fixed or not ?

Comment: You call .setStyle() twice in here; once for bigText and once for the bigPicture.  Is this intentional?